# TestNG Master Suite wont run Chrome suite

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, testing, webdriver, testng

Im trying to run a suites from a master suite file but when i run the TestNG suite nothing happens as in the suite never starts.

If i run the mozilla suite the runs properly but when i run the Chrome suite im getting the error below. Any help would be appreciated.

Master Suite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Chrome Test Suite" verbose="1">
    <suite-files>
                <suite-file path="./CAR_MozillaTestSuite.xml"></suite-file>
                <suite-file path="./CAR_ChromeTestSuite.xml"></suite-file></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

CAR_MozillaTestSuite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Mozilla Test Suite">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Mozilla" />
    <parameter name="domain" value="Caribbean" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utils.Listener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Mozilla Test" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.common.LoginLogout_Test" />
        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

CAR_ChromeSuiteTest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Chrome Test Suite">
<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
<parameter name="domain" value="Caribbean" />
       <listeners>
              <listener class-name="utils.Listener"></listener>
       </listeners> 
   <test name="Chrome Test" preserve-order="true" > 
        <classes>
                <!-- ______________________________________________  JOBSEEKER SECTION ____________________________________________ -->
                    <class name="tests.common.LoginLogout_Test"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Error im getting when i run the master chrome suite

```
About to begin executing test Chrome Test
About to begin executing LoginLogout_Test.beforeMethod
Feb 26, 2016 12:24:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\workspace\IJ_Stash\src\main\resources\drivers\chromedriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher)
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your master suite file lying? folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path of the xml files. Dot indicates current folder.
If master suite is also lying in the same folder as src/test/java/suites, then use
./CAR_MozillaTestSuite.xml

By the way, you should have your suite files in src/test/resources and not in java folder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of moving the xml files to the resource folder and changing the path but the problem still persists. I've dug into the problem a little more and it looks like its a IEDriverServer issue. Ive updated the post.